# write note of guitar using two lists

Tags: python, list, text

I have two lists:

```
list1=('a','b','c')
list2=('2','1','3')
```

and a text file
the text file has 3 lines so I want to add 
`'a'` in the 2nd line 
`'-'` in others, 
`'b'` in the 1st line
`'-'` in others, and 
`'c'` in the 3rd line
`'-'` in others according to the list1 and list2 like this

```
xxxx-b-
xxxxa--
xxxx--c
```

Answer (score 0):

First task is to get the first list sorted correctly.  This is easy if you `zip` the two lists together and then sort based on the (int-converted) line number:

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list2 = ['2', '1', '3']
>>> sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda p: int(p[1]))
[('b', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('c', '3')]
```

Then you need to format the letter into the appropriate string.  I'd do that with something like:

```
'xxxx' + ''.join(char if char == letter else '-' for char in 'abc')
```

so all together it's:

```
>>> for row in [
...     'xxxx' + ''.join(char if char == letter else '-' for char in 'abc')
...     for letter, _line in sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda p: int(p[1]))
... ]:
...     print(row)
...
xxxx-b-
xxxxa--
xxxx--c
```

Now you just need to write it to the appropriate text file instead of printing it; since you don't specify how you want to do that (is it a specific text file?  is it the parameter to a function?  is it an existing file you're appending to?) I'll leave that part for you to fill in.  :)

Comment: thanks @Samwise you code didn't work for me. it's hard to understand too :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it but I think there is a good method than my

```
list1=['1','4','3','2']
list2=['a','b','c','d'] 
j=0
 while j < len(list1):
    with open("note2.txt",'r+') as f:
        line = f.readlines()
        note=""
        f.seek(0)
        for index,line in enumerate(line):
            if index==list1[j]:
                note+=line.strip()+ str(list2[j])+'\n'
            else: 
                note+=line.strip()+ '-\n'

        f.write(note)

    f.close()
    j+=1
```